# How to get devise custom User columns to save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am reading that the application controller needs to have a before filter: `before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?`
however, I am receiving this error:

> undefined method `before_filter' for ApplicationController:Class Did
>   you mean? before_action

How can I get the new User fields added with a migration to save with devise?

Comment: `before_filter` was removed in Rails 5.1 in favor of `before_action`. It's the same method by a different name, so just swap `before_filter` with `before_action` to get rid of this error. Aside from that, you'll probably get a better answer if you go into more detail about exactly what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.

Comment: With before_action, it  now raises another error regarding the protected method in the controller.  The 'devise_parameter_sanitizer.for' . It is suggesting 'fork' in replace of 'for'. The new user columns are not saving to the db. 
Is there an updated tutorial on adding columns to the devise User model?

Answer (score 0):

Add new column in to your database
after `In your ApplicationController.rb` Add

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
private
def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys:[:profile_pic,:fname,:mobile,:gender])
end
```

Here use keys  => your added fields